# Ruby on Rails Michael Hartl chapter 8.5 Test Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've seen this question asked another time, in which the current_user variable was defined twice. I had the same error in my code, however removing the second definition of current_user still does not resolve the error message that I am receiving. This is the error message that I get when running my test:

---

```
  1) Failure:
SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", created_at: "2016-06-06 19:15:21", updated_at: "2016-06-06 19:15:21", password_digest: "$2a$04$LkmHj4hHVcRoTuEH6icLs.E/GebaKaY2Y/TX5nqouIj...", remember_digest: nil>
+nil
```

---

This is my sessions_helper file:

---

```
module SessionsHelper
  #logs in the given user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  #remembers a user in a persistent session
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  #returns current logged in user
  #def current_user
    #@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  #end

  #returns the user corresponding to the remember token
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  #forgets a persistent session
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  #logs out the current user
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

---

This is my users_login_test file:

---

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "Login with invalid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    #simulate a user logging out in a different window
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end

  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end
end
```

---

This is my test_helper file:

---

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

---

This is my users.yml file:

---

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

---

I'm really not sure whats going wrong, but I think I'm just missing something. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

---

Edit: here is my user.rb file:

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    niqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  #returns the digest of a given string
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ?     BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                              BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  #returns random token
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  #remembers a user in the database for persistent sessions
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  #returms true if the given token matches the digest
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?    (remember_token)
  end

  #Forgets a user
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

end
```

---

edit: sessions_helper_test.rb:

---

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end

  test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post failing test?

Comment: Provide sources for SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11]:

Comment: test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

Comment: I think it might have something to do with your conditions for the if keywords in the `session_helper` like `if (user_id = session[:user_id])` those are no comparisons but assignments. So first resolve those.

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke Can you post your user model file(user.rb)?

Comment: @JovicaŠuša I just added it to the original post to make it easier to read

Comment: I thought that you post the whole file, as you posted others, but nevermind, do you have methods remember and authenticated? defined in that file?

Comment: @JovicaŠuša There was a problem with my original edit adding the user.rb file to my post, but now it should be up. I have the remember and authenticated? methods defined in the file.

Comment: Not really sure what is going on, can you add https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug to your project so that you can debbug your code easier.
Then you can check inside your current_user method what values are missing.

Comment: @JovicaŠuša Thanks for all the help! I'll add it right now. Hopefully I can find out what is going wrong.

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke can I get the link to your github repo? to check all the files

Comment: @Nirupa here is the link to my github repo: https://corourke24@bitbucket.org/corourke24/sample_app.git Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke is it private? coz I can't access it

Comment: @Nirupa I think it is private, this is my first project using github. Do you know how to make it public/give you access?

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke Go to the Bitbucket repository's  settings.
Untick the this is a private repository check box to make your repository public. 
Click Save repository details.

Comment: @Nirupa Thanks! I just made the repository public

Comment: Thanks.. let me check the repo and let you know once I figure it out

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke I still see the sessions_helper.rb having two log_out methods. Please change the whole file as I have given in answer. Also all tests are running fine in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sessions_helper.rb, the `# Logs out the current user` method has been defined twice in the file. According to this tutorial in ch.8, in order to run the test suite green you need following content in your file.

I think you messed this up during **listing 8.39** where you just need to add one line in the **log_out method.**

Please fill up the following code in the **sessions_helper.rb** and your tests would go green.

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
# Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

**Update:**
Also in the **app/models/user.rb** file according to listing 8.45, you need to add a line `return false if remember_digest.nil?`. So the **user.rb** file should be as following.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil? #Add this line
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end
```

Please let me know if you face any error further.

Comment: Thanks! I did have that error, however after making the correction to the log_out method I still receive the same error message.

Comment: Also can you please add your sessions_helper_test.rb file? It should be under sample_app/test/helper

Comment: I'm not sure how to ass code in the comments so I just added the sessions_helper_test.rb file to the end of my original post in an edit.

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke according to listing 8.45 we are supposed to add a line    return false if remember_digest.nil? in the app/models/user.rb. Please add that line and the test would run green. I'll update this in the answer.

Comment: So i went through all the files and you just need to update the two files I mentioned in answer and your project will run well. Hope this was helpful. I can email you the corrected project if you need.

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke please let me know if this solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks! You have completely solved my problem. This is my first time coding anything in Rails and while I debugged a few issues that I had before I couldn't figure out how to fix this one. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChristianO'Rourke Not a Problem :) My advice is just go slow and try to understand each line Michael tries to explain. Rails is really interesting specially with Rails Tutorial. Let me know if you have any doubts further and good luck. Also do me a favor and please mark this answer as correct.