# Session hash session[:user_id] in rails does not get reset when running log_out in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, rspec, session-cookies

I am testing the `log_out` method in `SessionsHelper` module as indicated in Hartl's tutorial [Basic Login - Hartl Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#cha-8_footnote-ref-15)

Below is my rspec code:

```
expect { helper.log_out }.to change( session[:user_id], :nil? ).from(false).to(true)
```

And error:

```
1) SessionsHelper#log_out empties session[:user_id]
 Failure/Error: expect { helper.log_out }.to change( session[:user_id], :nil? ).from(false).to(true)
   expected #nil? to have changed from false to true, but did not change
```

I'm basically using the Object attributes observation matcher to test it.

I've tried byebug-ing the test and verified the session[:user_id] gets set to nil:

[image: Session byebug]

However, running the tests says that `session[:user_id].nil?` does not change from `false` to `true` after running `log_out`

How can this be?

Comment: Please refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153040/stop-devise-from-clearing-session

Comment: @ABPrime I'm not using Devise.

Comment: Please refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37668136/2681997

Comment: @ABPrime That is not my problem. The observation matcher does not work. Maybe some other strategy is needed.

Comment: Try this : `expect { helper.log_out }.should change(session[:user_id], :nil? ).from(false).to(true)`

Comment: @ABPrime That didn't work either. Gave "#nil? expected to change, but wasn't given a block." I change it to `expect{ helper.log_out }.to change(session, :empty?).from(false).to(true)` and it worked. But I want to know why `(session[:user_id], :nil?)` wouldn't work.